# django form save but not redirect

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm make a store using django,
 I want when a add a new product not redirect to the cart page, only want that after save the item , I can see the same page
How I can make this

Answer (score 0):

if i get your question correctly, you want to redirect after adding a product, so thats how you do it

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

first import `redirect`

then in the function that serve the form

```py
form = NewProductForm() # Where New Product form is the form name you created

if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
   redirect('/')
```

this will ensure that after the form is saved the user will be redirected to the home page

of course you can add some stuff but add `redirect` after form.save()